# Duplicate record in mysql after INSERT

Tags: mysql, vb.net, vb.net-2010

Quick one for you.
I'm using the following code to insert a record into two tables in my mysql db...

```
SQLConnection.ConnectionString = connectionstring
    Try
        If SQLConnection.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
            SQLConnection.Open()
            Dim SQLStatement As String = "INSERT INTO hosts(name, description, host, type, port, hostname) VALUES('" & txtname.Text & "','" & txtdescription.Text & "','" & txthost.Text & "','" & cmbtype.Text & "','" & txtport.Text & "','" & Pinger.resolvedstatus.Text & "'); SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()"
            SaveData(SQLStatement)

            SQLConnection.Open()
            SQLStatement = "INSERT INTO credentials(hosts_linked_id, username, password, type) VALUES('" & hosts_linked_id & "','" & txtusername.Text & "','" & txtpwd.Text & "','" & cmbtype.Text & "')"
            SaveData(SQLStatement)
```

the `Savedata()` bit calls this function...

```
    Public Sub SaveData(ByRef SQLStatement As String)
    Dim cmd As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand

    cmd.CommandText = SQLStatement
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    cmd.Connection = SQLConnection
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    hosts_linked_id = CInt(cmd.ExecuteScalar())

    SQLConnection.Close()
    MsgBox("Host has been added - Host ID " & hosts_linked_id & "")
    txtname.Text = ""
    txtdescription.Text = ""
    txthost.Text = ""
    cmbtype.Text = ""
    txtport.Text = ""
End Sub
```

The code is working in that the necessary records are inserted into both the 'hosts' and 'credentials' tables, however in each table the record is inserted twice.

obviously I don't want duplicate records in my db, so can anyone help me stop it from performing the insert twice?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call it twice:

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
hosts_linked_id = CInt(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
```

Once as `ExecuteNonQuery` and second time as `ExecuteScalar()`

You need to remove one of them. Looking at the code, I guess maybe you need to introduce a parameter to `SaveData` method to say which one to use.

Comment: Awesome, thanks Szymon!
I've copied the savedata function to a seperate function for saving the credentials and call each of them seperately.

Answer (score 0):

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
hosts_linked_id = CInt(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
```

Remove `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` To avoid Insert Twice